# efficiently finding overlapping segments from a set of lists

Tags: algorithm, list

Suppose I have the following lists:

`[1, 2, 3, 20, 23, 24, 25, 32, 31, 30, 29]
[1, 2, 3, 20, 23, 28, 29]
[1, 2, 3, 20, 21, 22]
[1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16]
[16, 17, 18]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]`

Order matters here. These are the nodes resulting from a depth-first search in a weighted graph. What I want to do is break down the lists into unique paths (where a path has at least 2 elements). So, the above lists would return the following:

`[1, 2, 3]
[20, 23]
[24, 25, 32, 31, 30, 29]
[28, 29]
[20, 21, 22]
[14, 15, 16]
[16, 17, 18]
[19, 20]`

The general idea I have right now is this:

1. Look through all pairs of lists to create a set of lists of overlapping segments *at the beginning of the lists*. For example, in the above example, this would be the output:
   `[1, 2, 3, 20, 23]
   [1, 2, 3, 20]
   [1, 2, 3]
   [16, 17, 18]`
2. The next output would be this:
   `[1, 2, 3]
   [16, 17, 18]`
3. Once I have the lists from step 2, I look through each input list and chop off the front if it matches one of the lists from step 2. The new lists look like this:
   `[20, 23, 24, 25, 32, 31, 30, 29]
   [20, 23, 28, 29]
   [20, 21, 22]
   [14, 15, 16]
   [19, 20]`
4. I then go back and apply step 1 to the truncated lists from step 3. When step 1 doesn't output any overlapping lists, I'm done.

Step 2 is the tricky part here. What's silly is it's actually equivalent to solving the original problem, although on smaller lists.

What's the most efficient way to solve this problem? Looking at all pairs obviously requires O(N^2) time, and step 2 seems wasteful since I need to run the same procedure to solve these smaller lists. I'm trying to figure out if there's a smarter way to do this, and I'm stuck.

Comment: Essentially it looks like you want to decompose the depth-first tree into chains. However, it's weird that you represent the tree as paths and it's not clear how exactly you want to do the decomposition. On a side note, how can `29` appear at the end of two different lists? DFS does not revisit nodes

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't defined the problem. So no one can tell you how to solve it. You've only given one example of output and a potential, vaguely described algorithm.  If you give a precise description of what the output should be, then you might get useful help.

Comment: @NiklasB, I was hoping to not get into details, but this is a graph representing a water network (pipes, junctions, etc.). Water actually can flow from 2 directions into the same node. The paths I'm providing here are paths of same-flow. Take [1, 2, 3]. This means water flows from node 1 to node 2 to node 3. There might be a connection between node 3 and 4, but if water flows *from* 4 to 3 (and not from 3 to 4), then it won't be included.

Comment: @Gene, what is unclear about how I've defined the problem? I want unique path segments (where each segment is at least 2 nodes) that are taken from the beginning of the lists.

Comment: @Geoff So you are trying to solve the problem by first "reducing" it to a exponentially sized sequence of lists and then post-processing those into a linear amount of lists again? Or does your graph have any special structure, like a tree? Are you sure this is the actual problem you want to solve? Don't you rather want to solve the *original* problem efficiently?

Comment: @NiklasB, maybe http://i.imgur.com/4dsaDaV.png will make it clearer. That's an example of a water network. Node 1 is a reservoir, and all water flows out of there. The graphs can/do contain cycles. What I first do is generate paths of same-flow. Then, I want to do the above post-processing to decompose the paths of same-flow.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "paths of same-flow". Are you saying you are running a max-flow algorithm and then doing a flow decomposition? Also please include an image of the graph that originated in your example.

Comment: "Break down" is not a helpful description of what you want.  How to break down?  What are the numbers? Weights? Node numbers? What does the graph search have to do with it?  E.g., are you insisting only on common prefixes?  What if you have [1,2,3,4] and [3,4]?  Is the right answer [1,2], [3,4] or [1,2,3,4], [3.4]?  What about [1,2,3,4] and [5,6,3,4]?  [1,2,3] and [6,2,7]? Is [2] a common sequence?

Comment: @Gene, the graph search doesn't matter here, which is why I'm not getting into it. For the purposes of this algorithm, the graph search is done. This is a post-processing step to break down the paths I've generated from the search. [1,2,3,4] and [3,4] is simply [1,2,3,4] and [3,4] because there are no overlapping paths *at the beginning of the lists*. [1,2,3,4] and [5,6,3,4] is also just [1,2,3,4] and [5,6,3,4].

Comment: @NiklasB, again, it doesn't matter here because that's relevant to the DFS (which is not part of my question; I can do the DFS). But in water networks, water flow is very nonlinear. Looking at the example I gave above, water can flow into node 20 from both directions, for example. Paths of same-flow are just paths of flow in the same direction.

Comment: @NiklasB, you ask, "Don't you rather want to solve the original problem efficiently?" That may be one course of action. Basically, while doing the DFS, I could maybe generate the segments there.

Comment: So can there be an exponential amount of lists? Can they share suffixes of size > 1 that are not prefixes?

Comment: I'm trying to imagine the worst case scenario. I don't think there will be an exponential number of lists. At least there won't be in any of the problems I'm working with. "Can they share suffixes of size > 1 that are not prefixes?" - Yes. In the above example: [16, 17, 18] and [16, 17, 18, 19, 20] gets evaluated to [16, 17, 18] and [19, 20], and [19, 20] is not a prefix for any list.

Comment: Yes, if you throw the DFS tree away you are losing information about the branching. Or is it a DAG?

Comment: I guess one thing I could do is save the paths at each branch in the DFS because what I want to do is more or less take segments between DFS branches.

Comment: What is the expected result for [1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,5]?

Comment: [1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,5] -> [1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,5],[1,2,5] because we can't remove any prefix without invalidating one of the paths (e.g., if we use [1,2], then [1,2,5] becomes [5], which is an invalid path since it has < 2 elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by thinking about the problem slightly differently. Instead of thinking about sequences of nodes (where an edge is implicit between each successive pair of nodes), I'm thinking about sequences of edges. I basically use the algorithm I posted originally. Step 2 is simply an iterative step where I repeatedly identify prefixes until there are no more prefixes left to identify. This is pretty quick, and dealing with edges instead of nodes really simplified everything.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the solution is to modify a Trie to serve the purpose. Trie compression gives clues, but the kind of compression that is needed here won't yield any performance benefits.

The first list you add becomes it's own node (rather than k nodes). If there is any overlap, nodes split but never get smaller than holding two elements of the array.

A simple example of the graph structure looks like this:

```
insert (1,2,3,4,5)
graph: (1,2,3,4,5)->None
insert (1,2,3)
graph: (1,2,3)->(4,5), (4,5)->None
insert (3,2,3)
graph: (1,2,3)->(4,5), (4,5)->None, (3,32)->None
segments
output: (1,2,3), (4,5), (3,32)
```

The child nodes should also be added as an actual Trie, at least when there are enough of them to avoid a linear search when adding/removing from the data structure and potentially increasing the runtime by a factor of N. If that is implemented, then the data structure has the same big O performance as a Trie with a somewhat higher hidden constants. Meaning that it takes O(L*N), where L is the average size of the list and N is the number of lists. Obtaining the segments is linear in the number of segments.

The final data structure, basically a directed graph, for your example would looks like below, with the start node at the bottom.

Note that this data structure can be built as you run the DFS rather than afterwords.

[image: Prefix Compressed Trie]